# Create vendor.js bundle with pure npm script

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am trying out the modern approach to build javascript applications without Grunt or Gulp. I am creating my build utilities by just using the `scripts` key word in `package.json`.

It works great, but I ran into a challenge. Is there a good way to create separate `vendor.js` and `app.js` bundles without making every dependency explicit in the browserify command (or alternatively passing a list of deps to the browserify command)?

Something better than:

```
"dependencies": {
   "react": "latest",
   "react-dom": "latest",
   "redux": "latest",
   "d3": "latest"
},
"devDependencies": {
   "browserify": "latest" 
},
"scripts": {
   "vendor": "browserify -r react -r react-dom -r redux -r d3 > vendor.js",
   "app": "browserify -x react -x react-dom -x redux -x d3 ./app/main.js > app.js"
}
```

Preferable, I would recycle the information stored in the `dependencies` keyword. Obviously, I do not want bundle `devDependencies` or dependencies not used in my code (even though the latter can be prevented by good maintenance of the requirements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Whether the solution is very elegant, I'll leave up to you to decide. Basically it boils down to something like the following (incomplete, browserify not yet called) snippet:

```
  "scripts": {
      "init": "npm ls -json --depth 0 | jq .dependencies | jq keys[]",
      "vendor": "npm run --silent init | sed 's/\\(.*\\)/-r \\1/g' | xargs"
  },
```

The init script is used to extract the dependencies. The vendor script calls this script, and converts it to the input parameters for browserify.

Note 1: I'm using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to extract information from the dependencies tree.
Note 2: construction of the argument list can also be done in the init script. You will have to provide an environment variable to distinguish between the -r or -x options.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try this out. On that note, it seems switching to WebPack and using their configuration files might be a cleaner solution.